# Migrate OS and files from one VM to another (Oracle VirtualBox)

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I recently created a VM for work, Windows 10, 6GB RAM, 50GB harddrive. In this VM there are configurations for forward proxies in IIS and some other complex configurations I really do not want to have to go through again, the problem is though that the 50GB harddrive just wasn't big enough, now the VM crashes due to the lack of memory.

Is there a way I can copy everything from my current VM to a new one (already created with a 90GB HDD)? I really don't want to have to configure a new instance of Windows so I can work off it.

Even if someone could post a link pointing me in the right direction, that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The Virtual Box machine lives in a folder on your host machine. Identify that folder.  It has the machine file and associated files in that folder.

Copy the entire folder to your other computer and now you can run Virtual Box on the other computer and open the machine file.

I do this whenever I get a new computer - that is, copy the machine folders to the new computer (VMware in my own case).

Make sure you provide enough space on the new machine for the Windows 10 machine. I allow a minimum of 100GB.

This should all work fine.

Here is a Virtual Box support article.

[Move VBOX machine](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=98326)

> If you intend to use the VM under Virtualbox, just copy the guest's
> files and folders to the new computer and register the VM's .vbox file
> with Virtualbox.